# Array Store Exception using array copy

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a method in which I require to copy an array to another.

```
public void rotate (int movements){
  SuperList<T> temp = new SuperList<> ();
  if( movements != size ){
     for( int i = 0; i < size - movements; i++){
        temp.add( i, (T) (get( movements + i ))); 
        //System.out.println(i + movements);
     }
     for( int j = 0; j < movements; j++)
        temp.add( temp.size(), ( T ) (get( j )));
     System.arraycopy(temp, 0, this, 0, size);
  }
}
```

but when I execute it appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at unal.datastructures.SuperList.rotate(SuperList.java:42)
at unal.datastructures.SuperList.main(SuperList.java:65)
```

Comment: Can you show the `main()`..?

Comment: Why is your if condition stating `if( movements != size )`.? . Where is `size`.?

Comment: Do you know there is [Collections.rotate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List,%20int%29)?

Answer (score 1):

`System.arraycopy` copies between two arrays - you are applying it to two instances of `SuperList`, which is a collection (implements `List`, presumably).

Comment: SuperList extends from ArrayLinearList, in ArrayLinearList is implemented System.arraycopy and it works properly.

Comment: Assuming you mean [this](https://compilr.com/jhot55/taller/Taller/unal/datastructures/ArrayLinearList.java), you are using it wrong. ArrayLinearList uses `System.arraycopy` to copy its `element` data member, which is indeed an array (of T). It does not apply it to object references such as `this` or `temp` like you have in the code snippet you enclosed.